# Mac OS X PATH variable to python binary

Tags: python, shell, terminal

In a Terminal window I am running `$python3`.  This command exists in /usr/bin/ and points to the executable binary /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin/python3.  This results with the initiation of Python 3.4 command interface.  Now, I run `$python3.4`, which exists in /usr/bin/ as well, but points to the executable binary /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Python.  This also initiates the Python3.4 command line interface.  What is going on here?

Specifically, what is the reason that Python3.x is defaulting to 3.4.  I have tried the same things for commands `$python2.5` and `$python2.6` each of which exist in /usr/bin/ and point to respective binaries

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python2.5

and

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6

The versions of python reported at initiation of the command line interface are as expected. 2.5 for 2.5 and 2.6 for 2.6.

Comment: What is the output of `which python3` on your machine?

Comment: There's your answer. `python3` points to version 3.4. It's usually just a symbolic link that points to the most recent version, meaning you don't have to type `python3.x`. That saves typing, and avoids the user having to remember which version is installed, especially after updating.

Comment: @bnaecker `which` for each of the above binaries gives: `$which python3 python3.4 python2.5 python2.6`     
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4
/usr/bin/python2.5
/usr/bin/python2.6  Thank you for pointing out how to investigate.  I will need to figure out why the soft links as revealed by `ls -l python3 python3.4` point to binaries in the expected areas contradict this return of the `which` command...and then resolve the issue.

Comment: @bnaeker Thank you! That was very informative.

Comment: A nice way to summarize seems to be `$ls -l 'which python*'` (using backticks instead of apostrophes). This gives the resolution to the actual binaries that all the python* commands in /usr/bin/ (or any other directory) would execute.